# Span of four vectors in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Can we say that the span of the set of vectors $(1, 0, 0)^T, (0, 1, 0)^T, (0, 0, 1)^T, (1, 1, 1)^T$ is $\mathbb R^3$?

My answer would be yes as the span is the set of $(a+d, b+d, c+d)^T$ for all $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb R$.
Is this correct and is there a more elegant answer?

Comment: Your first 3 vector already span R3, so no need d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first three vectors $(1, 0, 0)^T, (0, 1, 0)^T, (0, 0, 1)^T$ already span $\Bbb R^3$ (in fact, they constitute an orthonormal basis) - so adding any more vectors to this collection (e.g. the fourth one $(1,1,1)^T$ in your post) does not affect the span. Note that $\operatorname{span} A \subseteq \operatorname{span} B$ if $A\subseteq B$.